# Adding array list to pyspark DataFrame

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am very new to Pyspark. I am trying to add the array list (list of files) which I gathered using "mssparkutils.fs.ls(WORK_FOLDER)" command to a DataFrame. But I am getting "TypeError: StructType can not accept object '20230205' in type <class 'str'>" error. Your kind help will be appreciated.

Code below:

==================================================================================

```
# Validation Id Checking
columns = StructType([StructField('Name',StringType())])
FileList = []
files = mssparkutils.fs.ls(WORK_FOLDER)
for file in files:
    if file.name.endswith('csv'):
            fileName = file.name
            array = fileName.split("_")
            for word in array:
                index = word.find('Exchange')
                if index != 0:
                    FileList.append(str(word))
print(FileList)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=FileList,schema=columns) `
```

========================================================================================

The print(FileList) command gives me below output:
['20230205', '001040.csv', '20230205', '200005.csv', '20230206', '200006.csv', '20230207', '200021.csv', '20230208', '200007.csv', '20230209', '200010.csv', '20230210', '200009.csv']

I am trying to add the "FileList" values to Dataframe df. Using the Column Name 'Name' s StringType.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the input file list has 2D structure before creating the dataframe

```
spark.createDataFrame([[item] for item in FileList], schema=columns)
```

Result

```
+----------+
|      name|
+----------+
|  20230205|
|001040.csv|
|  20230205|
|200005.csv|
|  20230206|
|200006.csv|
|  20230207|
|200021.csv|
|  20230208|
|200007.csv|
|  20230209|
|200010.csv|
|  20230210|
|200009.csv|
+----------+
```